# Spring Security is not recognizing user roles

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

It looks very strange behavior, probably a bug.
I have a Spring boot 1.3.2 as backend API using Rest Service and I have another application using Angular 2 consuming these services.
All the security stuff is working ok with JWT Token, I can restricted my services for logged users, I can check the user logged and so on. Authorization is not working 100%, If I add on my services `@Secured` or `@PreAuthorize` with some user role this work with swagger and with my MockMvc tests using `@WithMockUser(roles="ROLE_TEST")` so it's configured OK.

The problem is that Authorization with `@Secured` or `@PreAuthorize` is not working when I'm accessing via angular application, All my requests that has `@Secured` or `@PreAuthorize` I receive Status 403.

`authentication.getAuthorities()` that all my roles is being loaded perfectly

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@Secured("ROLE_MANTER_INSTITUICAO")
public List<HierarquiaInstituicao> getAll() {
    return service.findAll();
}
```

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled=true, jsr250Enabled=true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserService userService;
    private final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    public SpringSecurityConfig() {
        super(true);
        this.userService = new UserService();
        tokenAuthenticationService = new TokenAuthenticationService(userService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.exceptionHandling().and().anonymous().and().servletApi().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                // Allow anonymous logins
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()

                // All other request need to be authenticated
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()

                // Custom Token based authentication based on the header
                // previously given to the client
                .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserService userDetailsService() {
        return userService;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService() {
        return tokenAuthenticationService;
    }
}
```

My filter:

```
public class StatelessAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final TokenAuthenticationService authenticationService;

    public StatelessAuthenticationFilter(TokenAuthenticationService authenticationService) {
        this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        Authentication authentication = authenticationService.getAuthentication(httpRequest);
        if(authentication != null) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else {
            httpResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        }
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can we have a simple code example?

Comment: When the authentication is loaded in StatelessAuthenticationFilter, does it have the roles loaded?

Comment: @mad_fox Yes if I do Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>)    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities(); I can see all the roles loaded

Comment: Is the role loaded "ROLE_MANTER_INSTITUICAO" or is it "MANTER_INSTITUICAO". Try changing it to MANTER_INSTITUICAO if it is the former.

Comment: Is recorded at database as "ROLE_MANTER_INSTITUICAO" I tried with ROLE_ prefix and without ROLE_
My application was stopped because this bug. I have been working 10 years with spring, but this time I do not know what to do.